# Azure login using Django webapp

Tags: python, django, azure, authentication, web-applications

So, here is my question's overview:-

I basically want to login into azure account. I have created my azure login credentials from azure portal. And now i want to login into azure account but not from portal.azure.com site, I want to login through a webapp which i have developed using Django.

I have a webapp developed which has login and password textbox on my django site, now i want to enter my azure credentials here on this webapp and it should also get logged in on azure portal, rendering azure portal after login is not necessary.

Could anyone help me out here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for isn't really possible.

The ROPC flow could be used to acquire access tokens to APIs using a user's credentials. 
That won't setup single sign-on though. 
That requires interactive authentication on the Azure AD login page, so that it can set the cookie to track the SSO session.

Now if you want to access certain things on behalf of a user in your app, you can authenticate the user with one of the authentication flows offered by Azure AD. 
Authorization code flow / hybrid flow will probably work for your app.

But don't use ROPC. 
You should not be handling user credentials. 
It also won't work if the user has MFA and in some other cases.

Then once you have authenticated the user, you can get an access token to call the Azure Resource Management API or any other APIs that are available to your app.

Comment: Is it possible that, can we use PowerShell script in the background of Django code?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure why you would want to do that? :)